# Android - Simple JSON object response using Retrofit 2.1.0?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, android-json

When I connect to web service, it get me bellow `json` :

```
[
    {"Key":"Sucsess",
    "Value":{
    "Family":"Warton",
    "Name":"James",
    "Role":"student",
    "Status":"true"}
    }
]
```

How can I fetch data from this `json` ?

I use from this [SITE](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and get me two class :

1- `ModelSignIn.class` :

```
public class ModelSignIn {
    @SerializedName("Family")
    @Expose
    private String family;
    @SerializedName("Name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("Role")
    @Expose
    private String role;
    @SerializedName("Status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    public String getFamily() {
        return family;
    }

    public void setFamily(String family) {
        this.family = family;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

2- `JsonSignIn.class` :

```
public class JsonSignIn {
    @SerializedName("Key")
    @Expose
    private String key;
    @SerializedName("Value")
    @Expose
    private ModelSignIn modelSignIn;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public ModelSignIn getValue() {
        return modelSignIn;
    }

    public void setValue(ModelSignIn modelSignIn) {
        this.modelSignIn = modelSignIn;
    }
}
```

And how can I use from above classes in my code :

```
public class ConnectRetrofits {
    private void loadJSONLogin(String username, String password) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ConstUrl.BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        Interface_SignIn request = retrofit.create(Interface_SignIn.class);
        Call<ModelSignIn> call = request.getJSONSignIn(username, password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelSignIn>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ModelSignIn> call, Response<ModelSignIn> response) {
                JsonSignIn JSI = new JsonSignIn();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ModelSignIn> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And `Interface_SignIn.class` :

```
public interface Interface_SignIn {
    @GET("/GiveData.svc/login/{UserName}/{Password}")
    Call<ModelSignIn> getJSONSignIn(@Path("UserName") String UserName,
                                    @Path("Password") String Password);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `response.body()`?

Comment: `final JsonSignIn  docType = response.body();`

Add this in `onResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `body()` method to get your response model. In your case you have incorrect model in request though. In your case the response is an array for some reason. And the parent object is `JsonSignIn`. So you need to update your code accordingly.

```
public interface Interface_SignIn {
    @GET("/GiveData.svc/login/{UserName}/{Password}")
    Call<List<JsonSignIn>> getJSONSignIn(@Path("UserName") String UserName,
                                         @Path("Password") String Password);
}
```

Don't forget to update your request.

```
Call<List<JsonSignIn>> call = request.getJSONSignIn(username, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<JsonSignIn>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ModelSignIn> call, Response<List<JsonSignIn>> response) {
            List<JsonSignIn> JSI = response.body();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<JsonSignIn>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the gson converter, you can just cast the response to a ModelSignIn

```
 public void onResponse(Call<ModelSignIn> call, Response<ModelSignIn> response) {
                ModelSignIn msi = (ModelSignIn)response.body();
               ...
```

then you can just get the elements:

```
msi.getName();
```

etc...